# Bootstrap 3 layout with Panel display not correct on small device

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 to ajust my layout like below but not success on iPad (portrait).

Panel 3 obscured Panel 1 & 2. This problem occurs only in this size.

This is a bug???

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-looking-info">
                    <h4>
                        Panel 1</h4>
                </a><small>Panel heading description</small>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body in" id="panel-looking-info">
                Panel body 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-looking-info">
                    <h4>
                        Panel 2</h4>
                </a><small>Panel heading description</small>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body in" id="panel-looking-info">
                Panel body 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-looking-info">
                    <h4>
                        Panel 3</h4>
                </a><small>Panel heading description</small>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body in" id="panel-looking-info">
                Panel body 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can see problem on http://bootply.com/76904 when you resize to small size.

Any idea for this?

Comment: What layout are you looking for (for sm size)? Panel 1 and Panel 2 on first row, panel 3 under them?

Comment: Yes, as you say. Panel 1 and Panel 2 on first row, Panel 3 under them when viewing on browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update 2**

Also read: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10152#issuecomment-23247254. Instead of the float:left you should use a clearfix in combination with a responsive utility class for the viewport. See: http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/css/#grid (section "Responsive column resets").

So in your case: add `<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>` between the second and third panel column.

**update**

The overlap described below don't happen when all row div's (columns) have a float:left.

col-xs-12 and col-sm-12, etc don't have a float.

So to fix your problem add a float:left to your third column: `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="float:left;">`

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-looking-info">
                    <h4>
                        Panel 1</h4>
                </a><small>Panel heading description</small>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body in" id="panel-looking-info">
                Panel body 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-looking-info">
                    <h4>
                        Panel 2</h4>
                </a><small>Panel heading description</small>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body in" id="panel-looking-info">
                Panel body 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="float:left;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#panel-looking-info">
                    <h4>
                        Panel 3</h4>
                </a><small>Panel heading description</small>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body in" id="panel-looking-info">
                Panel body 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

<strike>Read about the grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid or http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/twitters-bootstrap-3-rc2-important-changes/ (easy example)</strike>

The bootstrap CSS has 4 grid (extra small with col-xs-*, small with col-sm-* etc.)

For every grid the number of columns should add up to 12.

In your code col-xs / col-sm add up to 36.

Depending on your wishes you have to choose your grid classes:

For three colums / panels:
Never stack / always horizontal: `<div class="col-xs-4">`

horizontal above 768px: `<div class="col-sm-4">`

horizontal above 992px: `<div class="col-md-4">`

horizontal above 1200px: `<div class="col-lg-4">`

NB you use the same id (panel-looking-info) three times

The docs on twitter bootstrap also show:

```
<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div
```

where col-xs-6 makes 3 div of 50% = 150% in a row:

check these examples with or without boostrap css:

```
<div style="width:800px;">
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:50%;float:left;min-height:50px;"></div>
<div style="background-color:orange;width:50%;float:left;min-height:50px;"></div>
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="height:150px;background-color:navy;"></div>
</div> 
<br>
<div width="800px">
<div style="background-color:yellow;width:50%;float:left;min-height:50px;"></div>
<div style="background-color:orange;width:50%;float:left;min-height:50px;"></div>
<div style="width:100%;position:relative;">
<div style="height:150px;background-color:navy;"></div>
</div>
```

The result:
[image]

The difference with the second is the position relative (the TB grid classes also add a position relative), but in both cases the elements overlap.

Cause the total width is > 100% elements overlap and have the same top.

I don't think this a bug. I think the docs on getboostrap.com are wrong.